# How to calculate total price in angular formarray and formcontrol

Tags: angular, forms, form-control

```
this.angForm=this.fb.group({
    status:[''],
    subtotal:[],
    tax:[],
    total:[],
    date:[],
    orderProducts:this.fb.array([]),
    paymentMethod:[''],
    customerFullName:[''],
    phone:[''],
    email:[''],
    shippingAddress:[''],
    deliveryNote:[''],
    city:[''],
    province:[''],
    postalCode:[''],
  })
}
```

this is the structure of the form,and orderProducts is the formarray

```
for(let i of this.items){
      this.ProductOrder.push(new FormGroup({
      productName:new FormControl(i.name),
      isDonation:new FormControl(false),
      isGift:new FormControl(false),
      comment:new FormControl(null),
      price:new FormControl(i.price),
      quantity:new FormControl(0),
      }),)
    }
```

in formarray,I have a formcontrol part show the productname and price and other field
the name and price I took it from database.
Now I tried to calculate the qty*price of all products

```
    <form [formGroup]="angForm">
<div formArrayName="orderProducts">
<div class="cart-item" *ngFor="let item of ProductOrder.controls;let i = index">
<br>
<div [formGroupName]="i">
    <mat-card class="card">
    <b>Item:</b>  
    {{ item.controls.productName.value }}<br>
    <b>Price:</b>   
    {{ item.controls.price.value}} &#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;
    <mat-form-field>
        <mat-label>Qty:</mat-label>
        <input matInput type="number" min="0" formControlName="quantity">
      </mat-form-field>
    <br>
    <mat-checkbox formControlName="isGift" >This is a gift</mat-checkbox> &#160;&#160;
    <mat-checkbox formControlName="isDonation">Donate it </mat-checkbox><br>
    <mat-form-field class="comment"> 
    <mat-label>Leave a comment</mat-label>
    <textarea matInput placeholder="I want ..." formControlName="comment" ></textarea>
    </mat-form-field><br>
```

[by this case, the total price should be 160, How can I calculate the price and display it dynamically in the same page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E1ojI.png)
this is the HTML part.
Thank you very much

https://github.com/febycloud/BakeryStore/tree/master/frontend/src/app/cart
Here is my full code 
Thank you for helping

Comment: you want to display total after user changes quantity value or just at the time the form is rendered ?

Comment: I want to display total after the user changes quantity, I tried to make valuechanges but I don't know how to take price and quantity out from formcontrols in formarry. Thank you for asking

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested this but if I'm understanding correctly this is what you want

```
var orderProducts = this.angForm.get('orderProducts') as FormArray;
var forms = orderProducts.controls as FormGroup[];
var qtyFormControls = forms.map(x => x.get('quantity'));

qtyFormControls.forEach(qfc => {
  var parent = qfc.parent; //FormGroup
  qfc.valueChanges.subscribe(qty => {
     var itemTotal = qty * parent.get('price');
     parent.get('itemTotal').setValue(itemTotal );
     console.log("Item total: ", itemTotal ))
     calculateCartTotal();
});
```

don't forger to unsubscribe in ngOnDestroy() lifecycle hook to prevent memory leaks

UPDATE:

To get live subtotal of different items we can add another FormControl called subTotal to FormGroup controls within orderProducts FormArray and populate it with total for that product then recalculate order total:

```
var total = 0;
var calculateCartTotal = () => {
  total = forms.map(x => +x.get('itemTotal').value)
               .reduce((acc, val) => acc + val);
}
```

Comment: thank you but how to calculate all totals if they have different products

Comment: thank you very much, I added a subtotal via item and the new code is for(let i of this.items){
      this.ProductOrder.push(new FormGroup({
      productName:new FormControl(i.name),
      isDonation:new FormControl(false),
      isGift:new FormControl(false),
      comment:new FormControl(null),
      price:new FormControl(i.price),
      quantity:new FormControl(0),
      subbyitem:new FormControl(0),
      }),)
 } and in HTML is <input formControlName="subbyitem" matInput type="number" value="{{item.controls.price.value *item.controls.quantity.value}}" #subprice> <be>

Comment: but I couldnt update the changes when user input values

Comment: hmm I'm not sure you'll have to post code somewhere like stackblitz so I can take a look

Comment: https://github.com/febycloud/BakeryStore/tree/master/frontend/src   here is my code , the app/cart is the part

Comment: ok, I forked your repository, updated logic and created pull request into your repo https://github.com/febycloud/BakeryStore/pull/3 or just look at mine if that's easier https://github.com/ihorbond/BakeryStore

Comment: Thank you very much I will check it now

Answer (score 0):

This would help:

```
        this.sum = 0;
        this.details().value.forEach(x => {
              this.sum += +x.price;
        });
        console.log(this.sum)
        this.detailsForm.controls['total'].setValue(this.sum);
```